# Junit test loop condition with user input

Tags: user-input, junit4, do-while

I have a function that would keep looping until it got a correct username input. I try to write the unit test of it, but cannot figure out a proper way. The test always failed at the scan.nextLine(). Can anyone help? 
Function:

```
 User currentUser = null; 
 String name = null;   
 do {
         System.out.print("Please enter your user name: ");
         name = scan.nextLine();
         currentUser = User.userExist(name); //if user exist return user, else return null
         if (currentUser == null)
            logging.log("<LOG> Non-existent user "+name+", Please enter again!");
     }while(currentUser == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests (assume your using jUnit) are supposed to run without any human input.  Your best bet is to simulate the user input by creating a mock object of the scan class and have your tests set the mock object during setup.

EG something like this (pseudo code):

```
// test class
@Before() {
    MockScan mockscan = new MockScan();
    classToTest.setScan(mockScan);
}

// mock class - should implement same interface as original 
// scan object or extend it and override its methods
class MockScan implements ScanInterface {
    public String nextLine() {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

If the object you need to mock is complicated or provided by the system there are a few frameworks out there to help - search google.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try like that to work `scan.nextLine();`

```
User currentUser = null; 
String name = null;   
Scanner scan = null

while(currentUser == null)
     System.out.print("Please enter your user name: ");
     scan = new Scanner(System.in);   //to ask user input
     name = scan.nextLine();
     currentUser = User.userExist(name); //if user exist return user, else return null

     if (currentUser == null)
        logging.log("<LOG> Non-existent user "+name+", Please enter again!");
     else
        scan.close();
 }
```